# Result showing that a certain valuation ring in some function field has to be a DVR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I know that if $R$ is a valuation ring such that $0 \to \mathbb{C} \to R$ is a left-split exact sequence, then there exists a discrete valuation ring $C$ with $R \subset C$ so that $0 \to \mathbb{C} \to C$ is also a left-split exact sequence.

How can the above be used to show that a certain valuation ring in some function field, of which I can't think of at the moment, has to be a DVR, with applications in particular to complex algebraic curves?

Comment: Could you give a reference for the result mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: The result is essentially the construction of DVRs at the end of the valuation ring chapter in Atiyah-Macdonald.